# Open PDF in Reader and wait until it exits

Tags: java, pdf, process, wait, system-calls

Is it possible to open a PDF in Adobe Reader so that the user can fill out the form, and then wait until / be notified when they close it?

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file);
```

seems to return immediately (so Process#waitFor is no help), and

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

doesn't give any indication of when the file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

[JustFormsPDF](http://www.justformspdf.com/index.asp) appears to let you render a PDF using Swing components and collect the data that way, which would be a really nice option. Only problem is it appears to have been last updated in 2004.

Comment: [jPDFNotes](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfnotes/) looks like another option, but it's not cheap.